# mysql Subquery with JOIN bad performance

Tags: mysql, performance, join, subquery

My problem is this:

```
select * from 
    (
    select * from barcodesA 
    UNION ALL 
    select * from barcodesB
    )
    as barcodesTOTAL, boxes
 where barcodesTotal.code=boxes.code;
```

Table barcodesA has 4000 entries
Table barcodesB has 4000 entries
Table boxes has like 180.000 entries

It takes 30 seconds to proccess the query.

Another problematic query:

```
select * from 
    viewBarcodesTotal, boxes
 where barcodesTotal.code=boxes.code;
```

viewBarcodesTotal contains the UNION ALL from both barcodes tables. It also takes forever.

Meanwhile,

```
        select * from barcodesA , boxes where barcodesA.code=boxes.code
        UNION ALL 
        select * from barcodesB , boxes where barcodesB.code=boxes.code
```

This one takes <1second.

The question is obviously WHY?, is my code bugged? is mysql bugged?

I have to migrate from access to mysql, and i would have to rewrite all my code if the first option in bugged.

Comment: In short: subqueries are slow, avoid them where possible.

Comment: You might want to run EXPLAIN on the query and include that output in your question. Otherwise, do you have indexes on the code fields? Do you really need to obtain all the data or a subset (based on a condition) would be enough?

Answer (score 0):

Add an index on `boxes.code` if you don't already have one.  Joining 8000 records (4K+4K) to the 180,000 will benefit from an index on the 180K side of the equation.

Also, be explicit and specify the fields you need back in your SELECT statements.  Using * in a production-use query is bad form as it encourages not having to think about what fields (and how big they might be), not to mention the fact that you have 2 different tables in your example, `barcodesa` and `barcodesb` with potentially different data types and column orders that you're UNIONing....

Comment: barcodesA, barcodesA  contains a barcode associated to clothes.  Boxes  contains like 20 barcodes associated to a box. Where should i put the indexes?  Also, i dont use select * , i just wanted to simplify it can be read more easly.

Answer (score 0):

The REASON for the performance difference...

The first query says... First, do a complete union of EVERY record in A UNIONed with EVERY record in B, THEN Join it to boxes on the code.  The union does not have an index to be optimized against.

By explicitly applying your SECOND query instance, each table individually IS optimized on the join (apparently there IS an index per performance of second, but I would ensure both tables have index on "code" column).

Comment: How can i check the index?

What column should it be?
Remember the tables: 

barcodesA >   barcode, seasson, model, colour

barcodesB >   barcde, seasson, model, colour.------.

:::::example::::: 
84232323232, 1, 100, 225
boxes >   boxNumber, barcode, details
:::::example::::: 
000000000001, 84232323232, whatever

Comment: @Fran, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-information.html shows "Describe Table {yourTable}" command (among others)

Comment: Would you need a screen capture?

Comment: you should be able to use the MySQL tools that allow you to look at your databases, run queries, edit stored procedures, etc...  Click on the table to modify and it should bring up a dialog window.  Along the bottom (from what I remember) are labels for columns, indexes, constraints, triggers, etc... click on the one for triggers and it should list the indexes on the table(s).  You should see one where the column indexed would include the code column.